# Xbox 360 charger to charge Xbox One controller

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, xbox-one

I have a couple of questions.

1. I have Insignia XBox 360 controller charger (dual slot one); and I sold my XBox 360 and have two ONE- controllers. Is there an adapter to use that docking station to charge the device?
2. Will XBox 360 rechargeable battery fit XBox one? I'm 99% sure it won't but, I don't have the 360's rechargeable battery on hand to test it out myself.
   Thanks.

Comment: Please only ask one question per question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean a rechargeable battery pack like [this](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/images/images2500x2500/microsoft_b4u_00039_xbox_360_rechargeable_battery_1031624.jpg) - no that won't fit the Xbox Ones controller.  The Xbox One controllers do not have a separate piece like the Xbox 360 controllers did that you'd insert the batteries into or in the case of a rechargeable pack, they do not make use of the gold pins like the 360 controllers do.  The batteries on an Xbox One controller are more inline with the controller - making the back of it flat unlike the 360s.

If you get an [Xbox One rechargeable battery pack](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/accessories/batteries-chargers/play-and-charge-kit), it will come with a micro-USB cable to use for it (the Xbox One controllers have a micro-USB socket at the top of them which can be used to charge such battery pack or to power the controller/plug into a computer), but otherwise, they are fairly cheap and common to find anyway - should you go with a third-party option that does not include one.  There likely is not an adapter for the docking station you already have (its too specific of an adapter for manufactures to make and therefore, its not in anyone's interest to create such an adapter).  Insignia has instead opted to [make another charger station](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/insignia-dual-controller-charger-for-xbox-one/4733401.p?skuId=4733401) for the Xbox One.